# display cell like block without rowspan

Tags: html, css

http://jsbin.com/uzojax/2/edit

Above is my jsbin i have to display cell 8 in block without rowspan attribute and without disturbing html table structure of that cell
how it woud be possible.

Comment: Why do you want it without rowspan?

Comment: Hi, having a JSBin is great, but please also incorporate the relevant code in your question. Thanks!

Comment: see above js fiddle ..i m dragging on cells student name alloted on that time if user select 3 cells then i have to display student name in block also same for selection of two cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display the cell as a block or inline block as you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dCgzh/1/

You can use position: relative, but it will position the cell relatively to the position it had inside the table, which makes settings its position and width a little harder, because the cell doesn't 'know' the properties of the surrounding cells.

If you use position: absolute (like in the fiddle), then the positioning is relative to the body, or a container element that has a positioning itself. With that method, you can position the cell on the left of the table. In the fiddle, the table has 'position: relative'. Allowing you to position the cell on the left of the table and giving it the same width (100%) of the table.

```
  .csstdred {
    display: block;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
  }
```

There is no CSS equivalent of rowspan, which makes sense. Tables are for tabular data. Thus, the table is an integral part of the page structure. Therefore, attributes like rowspan cannot be seen as just styling, so they are available as separate HTML attributes instead of CSS styling.

Comment: see   jsfiddle.net/EAETy  ..i m dragging on cells student name alloted on that time if user select 3 cells then i have to display student name in block also same for selection of two cells

Comment: You can use the way I demonstrated in my (just modified) answer, but setting the right height is hard. You cannot use 300%, because the cell will become 3 times the height of the table. `tr`s don't accept `position: relative`, otherwise, you could still use 300%. At the moment, I think your only option is specifying fixed heights, so make the cell 15px or 1em and make the cell 45px or 3em, combined with the positioning as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: can u modified ur fiddle in jsbin because i m not seen jsfiddle html in my browser

Comment: <table id="tableAppointment" style="position: relative" runat="server" width="100%"
        cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#cccccc"></table>